# resize svg file width 100% and height fixed.

Tags: svg, sketch-app

### I made this svg file with sketch.app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="478px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 478 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.3.1 (12002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>フッター</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="ツリー" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="フッター" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
            <rect id="Rectangle-3-Copy" fill="#EFAE00" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="0" y="0" width="478" height="36"></rect>
            <path d="M160.5,36 L478,36 L478,0 L141,0 L141,0.467532468 L103,36 L160.5,36 Z" id="Rectangle-3-Copy-2" fill="#3D4D5A" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### I want to resize to width 100%, height 36px

I change

```
<svg width="478px" height="36px" ....>
```

↓

```
<svg width="100%" height="36px" ....>
```

but not work.

How to resize?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum If it's about code, shouldn't it be on *StackOverflow*, not SuperUser?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: @MarkMussler Ooops! Yes, you're right, I mixed up the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

It will stretch the width to 100%.

Here's the code of working svg;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100%" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 478 36"  preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 

xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.3.1 (12002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>フッター</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="ツリー" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="フッター" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
            <rect id="Rectangle-3-Copy" fill="#EFAE00" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="36"></rect>
            <path d="M160.5,36 L478,36 L478,0 L141,0 L141,0.467532468 L103,36 L160.5,36 Z" id="Rectangle-3-Copy-2" fill="#3D4D5A" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```